# mysql datatype for numbers maximum character length 19 precison 17

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

Was wondering if someone could help me on a data type questions for mysql. I would like to be able to load in numbers with maximum character length of 19 but with a maximum precision of 17 (so can have 17 digits after the decimal). I have tried using float(19,17) and decimal(19,17) but when i try loading a number such as 02.11111111112222222 it will not capture the full number. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql Will store this value as `2.11111111112222222` i.e. without the leading 0.

check mysql documentation for decimal type, it says:
**DECIMAL columns do not store a leading + character or - character or leading 0 digits. If you insert +0003.1 into a DECIMAL(5,1) column, it is stored as 3.1. For negative numbers, a literal - character is not stored.**

The leading 0 case applies to your value and mysql is not storing that. Hence, you are getting `2.11111111112222222` stored in the table.

check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

If you want to store leading zero as well change the definition by including UNSIGNED ZEROFILL after the datatype:

`CREATE TABLE your_table
 (
    your_column DECIMAL(19,17) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL
 );`

Just to make a note:

1. if you are entering `2.11111111112222222` you will get a zero padded to make the digit count 19-17 for before decimal point and get `02.11111111112222222`
2. if you are entering `02.111111111122222` you will get zero padded in right to make the digit count after decimal point as 17.

Comment: Many Thanks this loaded - i did get truncated warnings on some numbers within the criteria but still loading in as i wanted.

Comment: Glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use decimal

```
  decimal(19,17)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: Simple and elegant :)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat  .. also 3 type  ..or more  eg: `function { \n } ..also yiur last  is a good comment

Comment: Ok  .. anyway  i use both .. for function  ..  class  .{} ..a function not class \n {}